# Cryptographic library quality

Tags: tls

I've been working on a project that will require secure communication over the internet, so I've been thinking of TLS 1.2. After looking around I chose [Botan](http://botan.randombit.net/) but then I thought about using a more common one, OpenSSL. But since Heartbleed I've been reading quite a bit about problems with OpenSSL, and it seems to be rather poorly documented. I'm a decent programmer, but I don't know nearly enough about cryptography to evaluate a library on anything else than ease of use.

My question is this: Is there any way for me to evaluate the cryptographic strength and solidness of a library without paying a code review firm to go through the entire library?

Or do I just pick one that appear solid? My current alternatives are [Botan](http://botan.randombit.net/) and [PolarSSL](https://polarssl.org/), both appear easier to use than OpenSSL.

Comment: There is no answer here that is not at least opinionated. After the last debacle using a non-managed language (read: one that not intrinsically protects against buffer overflows), I would not consider anything in C. As Botan is object oriented C++ it would come slightly closer. FIPS certification is clearly not enough; it may even be detrimental to perform certification.

Comment: Why would FIPS be detrimental?

Comment: Because it takes a lot of resources away from actually developing the library. They are paper procedures mostly. Furthermore, FIPS and CC (CC much more so) have the nasty side effect that they do not promote updates to libraries.

Comment: Ah, ok. Could i reword this question to make it more factual, something along the lines of "Factors to consider when choosing a crypto library"?